# How to pass object type parameter from one C# cmdlet to another

Tags: powershell

I have written a C# powershell cmdlet that fills up custom objects from json file. Now I need to pass the object to other C# cmdlets that follow
Thanks

Comment: Store it as variable then pipe it to second cmdlet  
`$a = Your-cmdlet `;  
  
`$a| Second-cmdlet`

Comment: [`WriteObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms568371(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, writeobject is what I wanted.  Thanks to both